# Flutter I don't know how to select 'enum' pages in drop down button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dropdown

```
List<String> ilac_items = ["İlaçlar","İnsektisit", "Fungusit", "Herbisit"];
String? selectedIlacItem = "İlaçlar";



 DropdownButton<String>(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                        color: _selectedPage == Page.ilac ? active : notActive,
                      ),
                      value: selectedIlacItem,
                      items: ilac_items
                          .map((String item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: item,
                          child: Text(item,style: const TextStyle(color: AppColor.mainColor))))
                          .toList(),
                      onChanged: (item) => setState(() {
                       selectedIlacItem = item;
                      }),)
```

I want to sort the subcategory products under the category with the dropdown button, but I can select it in the drop down menu, but I don't know how to bring the page, can you help?

Comment: are you saying you like use `enum`  in dropDown?

Comment: I am using different enum page for each category but I have no idea how to do it in dropdown.

Comment: you like to open second drop down based on 1st dropdown selection?